# Bootstrap 3.0: Trigger when content moved under a with fix nav bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have fixed the bootstrap 3.0 navbar at the site top. For large content, when user scroll down the site content moves below it. 
A sample at: http://www.bootply.com/wgOrXN2R2b

I want to set a css on navbar as soon as user scrolls and the page content moves below navbar, and remove the css as soon as user scroll up and content is no more below navbar. (The css will add a box shadow to nav and make a thin transparent line while the content moves below it)

I used below js:

```
 function scroll() {        
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $('#content').offset().top) {
            $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass('fadeOut');
        } else {
            $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass('fadeOut');
        }

    }    
    document.onscroll = scroll;
```

But as you can see in sample, it does not work fine and the css applies after some row.

Comment: Its actually working fine!! Just change the color of `boxshadow` to `black`.. See this **[bootply](http://www.bootply.com/yAt7o9ZxdU)**

Comment: It is displayed when four lines already moved under menu, not as soon as first line. I am not a jQuery guy but my if statement is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to account for the height of the navbar

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > ($('#content').offset().top - 50)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a cleaner way to do what I think you're after using Bootstrap and their  affix javascript module. Check out their documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix

To achieve what you're after, using bootstrap, simply add this to the div you want to modify, altering the offset values as required (**but for this to work, you'll need to make sure you're calling your bootstrap.js file**):

```
  data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="60" data-offset-bottom="200"
```

Which in your case to alter the navbar, you will apply it like this:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="60" data-offset-bottom="200">
```

What will happen with this is you'll get 3 classes applied to your navigation bar. When it's close to the top, it will be .affix-top, when its close to the bottom you'll get .affix-bottom, and when it's neither, you'll get .affix.

.affix will apply a "fixed" class using default bootstrap css, but you can essentially build your own specific classes around those 3 things using the offset values. Your navbar can have dropshadow applied by default, but when it's got .affix-top, remove it.

Comment: @WilliamsGFX can you provide a sample ?! I can not make it run. Please see http://www.bootply.com/OXeQGpBe0M , which event will be triggered when content starts moving under affix

Comment: The reason I think this wasn't working for you is because you're not including the bootstrap javascript library in your example.